What's the meaning of "values time" in Family and Friends Starter book?
In Family and Friends Starter book, after three unit, there is a unit. The name of the unit is "values time". I can't understand the meaning of it. Would you please explain it?

Please look up these words in a dictionary, then ask about the questions that remain afterward. The answers will be more helpful to you.




In this context, values would be defined as:

(n.) principles or standards of behaviour; one's judgement of what is important in life.

So a person with values does the right thing.
As for time, the phrase "X time" refers to the time designated for the activity X, such as in dinner time (when you eat dinner) or tummy time (when a baby spends time on their tummy).
So in this context, "values time" is the period of time spent learning values (good behavior).  And in the above example, the value being studied is "Be kind to animals".
The phrase "values time" is certainly not commonly used.

This is a good answer, though I would argue that the meaning of “time” here, and in “dinner time” and “tummy time,” is not “the duration of time spent on this activity,” but “the time designated for this activity,” like the way the show Adventure Time answers the question “What time is it?”

I would add that, in my experience, values time is absolutely not an established phrase, and I didn't understand what it meant until I saw the image above.

Thanks for the helpful feedback; I've edited accordingly.
